# LINQ OrderBy with index ; getting error using Generic TKey

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I am trying to order an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` based on the index of the selected property:

```
class MyClass 
{
 public string Name;
 public string Value;
}
```

I have a helper method to get an `Expression<>` of the criteria.
It is compiled to create the `Func<>` to help with the ordering.
I'm having trouble trying to make the `Func<>` return a Generic `TKey` to be ordered.

```
public Expression<Func<T, TKey>> Helper<T>(int propIdx)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "record");
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    if(propIdx > props.Count()) 
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>)(Expression.Constant(true), param);

    Expression propExp = Expression.Property(param, props[propIdx].Name);

    return lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(propExp, param);
}
```

This is used to help with dynamic order criteria.

```
OrderByIdx(IEnumerable<MyClass> input, int propIdx)
{
     Expression<Func<T, TKey>> exp = Helper(propIdx);
     
     var funct = exp.Compile();

     return input.OrderBy(funct);
}
```

I am getting an error `The type or namespace TKey could not be found`

How can I use a Generic`<TKey>` to help with the ordering ?

Comment: Oops, changed `Fun` to `Func`. Its just the ordering function to be put inside the `OrderBy(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: `Type.GetProperties` doesn't have a defined order.

```
var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

Which property will be in `props[0]`? And are all properties readable?

So if you want to get a defined order, my advice would be to do some sorting. For instance get the public readable properties ordered by name.

Furthermore, isn't it a bit weird if users of your code (= software, not operators) want to use your generic code based on an index?

- They have a class `MyClass` with a property `Date`
- They have a sequence of objects of this class.
- They want to order by property `Date`
- Instead of ordering by property `Date`, or by property named "Date", They have to determine the index of property `Date`: Date seems to be the fourth property
- Then they have to call your method using this index: "OrderBy index 4"

Wouldn't it be easier if they could just say: "order by property `Date`", or "order by the property that is named 'Date'?

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> source = ...
var orderedSource = source.OrderBy(t => t.Date);
```

Sometimes your users don't have access to the property, they only know the name of the property. In that case you could create an extension method where you provide the name of a property, and that returns the ordered source.

If you are not familiar with extension methods. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

Usage would be something like:

```
var orderedSource = source.OrderBy(nameof(MyClass.Date));
```

or for instance: "order by the selected column in my DataGridView".

```
string propertyName = this.DataGridView.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Where(column => column.IsSelected)
    .Select(column => column.DataPropertyName)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var orderedSource = source.OrderBy(propertyName);
```

Such a procedure would be easy to make, easy to use and reuse, easy to test, easy to maintain. And above all: they are one-liners:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    string propertyName)
{
    // TODO: handle invalid input
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    // TODO: handle invalid propertyname

    return source.OrderBy(propertyInfo);
}

public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    // TODO: handle invalid parameters
    return source.OrderBy(t => propertyInfo.GetValue(t) as propertyInfo.PropertyType);
}
```

If desired you could create overloads for `ThenBy(this IEnumerable<T>, ...)`.

**But I want to order by Index, not by Name!**

If you really want to sort by index, it is easier to create extension methods with Lambda expressions, then to fiddle with Expressions.

Consider the following extension methods:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    int propertyIndex)
{
    return source.OrderBy(propertyIndex, GetDefaultPropertyOrder(typeof(T));
}

public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    int propertyIndex,
    IReadOnlyList<PropertyInfo> properties)
{
    // TODO: handle null and out-of-range parameters
    PropertyInfo sortProperty = properties[propertyIndex];
    return source.OrderBy(sortProperty);
}

public static IList<PropertyInfo> GetDefaultPropertyOrder(Type t)
{
    return t.GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.CanRead)
        .OrderBy(property => property.Name)
        .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
BindingList<MyClass> myObjects = ...

// display myObjects in a dataGridView
this.DataGridView.DataSource = myObjects;

// event if operator clicks on column header:
public void OnColumnHeaderClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    DataGridViewColumn clickedColumn = GetClickedColumn();

    // sort by column index, as you prefer:
    var sortedObjects = myObjects.SortBy(clickedColumn.DisplayIndex);
    ProcessSortedObjects(sortedObjects);

    // but of course, you skip some intermediate methods if you sort by property name
    var sortedObject = myObject.SortBy(clickedColumn.DataPropertyName);
    ProcessSortedObjects(sortedObjects);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I wasn't aware that the ordering wasn't defined.  I figured it would use the same order as the class definition. 
The reason to order by index is that is all I am able to get from the javascript client. 
or maybe I need extra client-side processing to extract the name and pass it to my MVC controller.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to order on a property, it must be of a type implementing `IComparable`. You can use this fact to replace `TKey` by `IComparable` in your code:

```
class MyClass 
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Value { get; set; }
}

public Expression<Func<T, IComparable>> Helper<T>(int propIdx)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "record");
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    Expression propExp = Expression.Property(param, props[propIdx].Name);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IComparable>>(propExp, param);
}

IEnumerable<MyClass> OrderByIdx(IEnumerable<MyClass> input, int propIdx)
{
     Expression<Func<MyClass, IComparable>> exp = Helper<MyClass>(propIdx);
     
     var funct = exp.Compile();

     return input.OrderBy(funct);
}
```